# Setting the WindowHeight property (read only)

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to get a continous form to cover the entire screen, even when there aren't enough records to cover the screen size.  Obviously, when I make the size of the detail appropriate it displays only a single record per screen-size.  I tried setting the WindowHeight property to the correct size in twips, but a dialogue appears informing me that the WindowHeight property is set to read only.  How do I disable this?

Comment: Any chance you have a screenshot that you could show what it is doing, then use some arrows to show what you want it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WindowHeight` is always a Read Only property (as are `WindowWidth`, `WindowTop` and `WindowLeft`).

You can modify the dimensions of the form using the `DoCmd.MoveSize` method, e.g. for the Open event, it might be something like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    DoCmd.MoveSize , , , 9500

End Sub
```

This leaves the window positioned where it is, and leaves the width unchanged, but sets the height to 9500 twips.

Comment: Perfect!  This did exactly what it needed to!